# What command will result in an in-text citation of a journal's name?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, article

I'd like to mention an academic journal's name in the text I am currently drafting. Using `\citetitle{elmo2022}`, I can get the name of the article printed into the final text. The same is true for commands like `\citeauthor{elmo2022}` and `\citeyear{elmo2022}`, which will respectively print:

> S. T. Elmo

> 2022

However, when I attempt to do a similar command to bring the journal name into the fore, I am presented with an error. Is this something that is possible? I hope to hear from you soon and let me know if this is incorrectly formatted, vis-a-vis your stack's conventions. To be clear, I'd like to do something like `\citejournal{elmo2022}` and get something like: *The Journal of Sesame Street Theory*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `biblatex` as the tag suggests you can define a `\citejournal` with `\DeclareCiteCommand` as shown below (the command is modelled after the standard definition of `\citeauthor`). If it's for a one-off where you don't want a new command, you can use `\citefield{<key>}{<field>}`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{journaltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  journal   = {Journal of Paleontology},
  volume    = {12},
  pages     = {37-37},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\citejournal{sigfridsson}

\citejournal{elk}

\citefield{sigfridsson}{journaltitle}

\citefield{elk}{journaltitle}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Elk 1972) Journal of Computational Chemistry Journal of Paleontology Journal of Computational Chemistry Journal of Paleontology]

---

If you are using `natbib` or another BibTeX-based solution, the journal is generally not available in citations. It would have to be provided via tricks like the `usebib` package.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{usebib}
\newbibfield{journal}
\bibinput{\jobname}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  journal   = {Journal of Paleontology},
  volume    = {12},
  pages     = {37-37},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{elk}

\usebibentry{elk}{journal}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Omg thank you! This is very useful and I appreciate your insight